# Statistics Possion and Binomial Joined Question?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

On average, a litter of cats has 5 kittens. Let X be the number of kittens in a litter of cats.

In 20 litters of kittens, what is the probability that at most 15 litters have exactly 5 kittens?

^^I am having trouble answering this question. If I set another variable Y = the number of litters that have exactly 5 kittens, then it becomes binomial with n=20, but the p value is unknown. This is where I get stuck.

Comment: Hello! You only said which is the expected value of $X$, how can you infer anything about the distribution? Maybe you missed a part of the text?

Comment: I guess X is assumed Poisson. What is $p = P(X=5)$?

Comment: Yes, X is Poisson, but another variable is required to answer the question.

Comment: Which I told you...